# When $a^2x^2+2bx+c$ is a perfect square?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, integers, elementary-functions

Is there any fast and easy method to find out $a^2x^2+2bx+c$ is a perfect square for some $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, i.e, when there is a $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$
a^2x^2+2bx+c=y^2
$$
where $a,b,c$ are given integers?

P.S.:
My question has two parts:

First decide if it is perfect square or not

Second fast and easy method to find $x,y$.

Thanks!

Comment: Wops nevermind sorry.

Comment: @stenvikteam Did you read the question?

Comment: @Arthur, Sure, as it is the discriminant of the usual method in solving quadratic equation, and in this question it is a necessary but not (unfortunately) a sufficient condition.

Comment: you want x which makes this term a perfect square for all $a$, $b$, $c$?

Comment: @Sil You're right. I really meant $4b^2-4a^2(c-y^2)$ needs to be a perfect square (i.e. there needs to exist a $y$ so that it becomes a perfect square), because that's the actual discriminant. In your example, $y = 1$ gives $16$.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer you full question but I may give you a way.
Were can write $a^2x^2+2bx+c$=$$(ax)^2+2ax(\frac {b}{a})+(\frac {b}{a})^2+[c-(\frac {b}{a})^2]$$=$$(ax+\frac {b}{a})^2+[c-(\frac {b}{a})^2]$$
Thus if the second part i.e. $[c-(\frac {b}{a})^2]$ is equal to 0 then it is a perfect square.
Then $ax+(\frac ba)^2$=$y$. So you can find the value of $x,y$. I am now still finding a good way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Given $a,b,c$ with $a\neq 0$, rewrite the equation in factored form

$$\left(a y-a^2x-b\right)\left(a y+a^2x+b\right)=a^2c-b^2$$

This leads to two linear equations

$$a y-a^2x-b=d_1$$

and

$$a y+a^2x+b=d_2$$

where $d_1, d_2$ are divisors of $a^2c-b^2$ such that $d_1 d_2=a^2c-b^2$

Comment: Nice but it does not assure that $x$ and $y$ will be integers, consider $a=1$, $b=0$, $c=2$. Then those equations do not have integer solution.

Comment: @Sil That is correct. If the system of two linear equations has no solutions with $x$ and $y$ integers, then the given expression is not a perfect square.

Comment: Exactly, and that is the same you could say about the original equation. In other words, this does not give any new information about the solution, or how to find it.

Comment: @Sil By writing a system of linear diophantine equations we have shown that the number of solutions of the original equation is finite. Furthermore there are necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of a solution of such a system.